# JMETER is very slow after a few hours

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, httprequest

I'm using `JMeter 3.1.1` to run  a load test. My test plan is with `40 threads` and each thread executes `6 HTTP Requests`. It is running fine for the first few hours with a latency of around `20ms`.
   After few hours, latency grows up to `500ms`. I verified that server is processing fine. Also, I have no 'Listeners' in my test plan and I run it in NonUI mode.
   Also it seems that the thread group is executing only one thread at time. Coz I see hardly one or two requests being executed by thread group per second.

Im really clueless what to suspect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

BTW., memory and CPU consumption are normal.

About my `TestPlan`:

```
Total Thread Groups:4

1. Setup Thread Group
2. Load test thread group with 40 threads
   (Action To be taken after error :Continue
    Ramp-Up period: 0
    Number of Threads: 40
    Loop Count: Forever)

2.1 Counter  
2.2 Random Variable  
2.3 User Defined Variables  
2.4 If Condition = true  
    - 2.4.1 HTTP Request1  
    - 2.4.2 HTTP Request2  
    - 2.4.2 Loop for 5 times  
        -- 2.4.2.1 HTTP Request1  
        -- 2.4.2.2 HTTP Request2  

3. Introspection thread group with 1 thread
4. Tear Down thread group
```

Please let me know, if more details are needed

Another observation is:
Server is having TIME_WAITs : 4418 (I check 'Use keep-alive' option for HTTP Request., still so many TIME_WAITs)

### Latest Observations(Thanks to one and all for your valuable comments)

Actually, the memory must be an issue., I have given already like this.,

-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=2048m

But I really wonder why JVM was not going 512 MB. So i tried with both Xms ans Xmx with 2g each. Now its kind of running for more longer. However it' performance is slowing down still. May be my Beanshell Post Processors are consuming all the memory. I really wonder why they are not releasing the memory.  If you see., per hour how the performance is degraded.
Hour    #Requests sent
----    --------------
Hour 1: 1471917
Hour 2: 1084182 (Seems all 2g heap is used up by this time)
Hour 3: 705471
Hour 4: 442912
Hour 5: 255826
Hour 6: 136292

I read that Beanshell hogs memory, but I have no choice but to use it as I have to use a third party jar with in the sampler to make few java calls. I'm not sure if I can do the same using JSR223(Groovy) or any other better performing sampler (pre / post processor)

Comment: can you please share your thread group configuration?

Comment: @Naveen: Add the info. Kindly take a look. THanks

Comment: there are two suspicious elements. 1) `Counter`, check whether you provided enough value at maximum field. 2) `If Controller`, the condition might be returning `false` in some cases.

Comment: @Naveen: If Controller - is not a problem. Becuase the the condition is setup at starting it will remain constant. And Counter is good as well. Coz it was still sending requests with proper counter., but very very slowly (one thread and one request per second)

Comment: Check JMeter resource utilization. Heap, CPU, memory etc. It could happen that JMeter itself is facing issue with resources.

Comment: Two most likely possibilities: 1. after few hours heap is filled up and jmeter is trying to do major GC and if not enough memory is cleaned, it will try major GC again and again. If this is the case, increasing heap and making sure you don't have resource eaters (most visualizers are in that category) will clean it up 2. based on your observation about TIME_WAITS, your server may be running out of ports. Make sure you have max ports configured adequately to support the test

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for your comments. I have updated the question with latest findings. Please take a look.

Comment: This thread saved lot of time.I experienced something similar that lot of if controller with java script put lot of stress on heap and excessive major GC impacts the transactions timing ultimately. Tried few options in GC but tuning GC is hell of time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, who all tried to help me.
However., I could resolve this.,
Culprit is : If Controller, which is evaluating the condition for every iteration of every thread. Sounds quite normal isn't it? The problem is., condition is evaluation is JavaScript based. So all threads are eating CPU and Memory for invoking JavaScript.
  Now Im getting consistent requests to server and JMeter is also almost stable at 1.9g of memory for 100 threads.
  Im posting this just in case any one can get benefited without wasting day and nights figuring out the issue :)

Comment: Hi i am facing a similar issue with loop controller. What did you use in place of if controller?

Answer (score 1):

as you have seen the Heap settings I did., here are the Memory and CPU Utilization of Jmeter. Im running 100 threads now. What should I do in my test plan to reduce the CPU utilization. I have a 100ms sleep after every 4 HTTP Requests.

PID   USER     PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
11850 xxx      20   0 7776m 2.1g 4744 S 678.2 27.4   6421:50 java

%CPU: 678.2 (Fluctuating between 99% - 700%)
MEM: 2.1g (Xmx = 2g)

Answer (score 0):

1) Do you run the JMeter with standard script (jmeter/jmeter.bat)?

Then mind that the default size for JVM heap in there is capped at 512M. Consider increasing it, at least at the maximum end (means, change default -Xmx512m).

Next thing to consider is the -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m default values.

Here's what Oracle suggesting:

> In heavy throughput environments, you should consider using this
>   option to increase the size of the JVM young generation. By default,
>   the young generation is quite small, and high throughput scenarios can
>   result in a large amount of generated garbage. This garbage
>   collection, in turn, causes the JVM to inadvertently promote
>   short-lived objects into the old generation.

So try to play with this parameters, that may help.

**P.S.** Aren't you, by chance, running it at AWS EC2 instance? If yes - what's the instance type?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have updated the question with latest findings. Please take a look.

Comment: I run bin/jmeter,   Im running on rhel6.6 linux box with 8GB mem and 8 core intel processor (2.20ghz) .